# What is wrong with my function to reverse a circular linked list.?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to reverse a circular linked list using three pointers but it is running. Program is executed but i think function is not executing. So please check it and found the error in my reverse function.

```
void reverse()
{
    struct node *p, *q, *r;
    p=head;
    p=q=NULL;
    int flag = 0;
    while(p->next != NULL)
    {
        flag = 1;
        r=q;
        q=p;
        p=p->next;
        q->next = r;
    }
    p->next = q;
    head = q; 
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the third line in function body, you do

```
p=NULL
```

And then in the while loop you access

```
p->next
```

But since here p itself is a NULL pointer, this gives you an error.

Feel free to comment if you still have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code:

- First you set `p = head`, but in the next statement you clear it. You probably intended to initialise `r` with `NULL`, but mistakenly assigned to `p`.
- The final assignment at the very end is wrong. You will miss one value. When you see that `p->next` has just been assign the value of `q`, it makes no sense that `head` should be assigned `q`, as obviously `p` is a *predecessor*. You should do `head = p` instead of `head = q`.
- The code will fail when the list is empty, i.e. when `head` is `NULL`. In that case the `while` condition will reference a NULL pointer. You could add a specific `if` statement for when `head == NULL`.
- Not important, but `flag` seems to serve no purpose. You can drop it.

```
void reverse()
{
    struct node *p, *q, *r;
    if (head == NULL) return;  // <--
    p = head;
    q = r = NULL;  // <--
    while (p->next != NULL)
    {
        r = q;
        q = p;
        p = p->next;
        q->next = r;
    }
    p->next = q;
    head = p;  // <-- 
}
```

Now, you can reduce the code by just allowing one more iteration of the `while` loop. Then you don't need the special condition for `head == NULL`, nor the additional assignment to `p->next` just after the loop (as that would happen in the extra iteration):

```
void reverse()
{
    struct node *p, *q, *r;
    p = head;
    q = r = NULL;
    while (p != NULL)  // changed!
    {
        r = q;
        q = p;
        p = p->next;
        q->next = r;
    }
    head = q;  // <-- now it should be q!
}
```